# How to download Ubuntu For Android?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

So I am stuck. I am trying to figure out where to download Ubuntu for Android and it isn't appearing anywhere on this site. Please help!

Comment: You mean [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android)? - you have to port it to your phone or something, but when I last checked there was not any clear instructions...

Answer (score 4):

The [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android) source code has not been released yet (and is non-trivial to integrate into an existing Android image, requiring some modifications to the graphics stack to share the HDMI port).

What you can play with right now is [Ubuntu Touch](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone), which is a full phone OS rather than something that coexists with Android.